# What are the notable difference between versions of SSMS?

Tags: ssms

I've been updating all the software at my new workplace, and people are asking me not to break something on accident if it's working. You know how it goes. But I'm also curious myself about what is different between SSMS versions. I just installed 17.5 last week and now there's 17.6 available and not much info out there about what changed over the years.

I've found a page listing changes in some of the 2016 versions and 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms

Wikipedia doesn't really have a versions history entry for SSMS specifically, just for the SQL server.

Is there a page somewhere listing all the notable changes between SSMS versions over the years? If there isn't I suppose we could compile an answer with that information here.

Comment: SSMS is just a GUI Tool to access your SQL Server database. Are you upgrading only the SSMS?

Comment: Yes, only SSMS. I'm not comfortable enough with updating the SQL Server itself yet (10.50), but I asked the current DBA here about it, and he's considering it, but he has the same questions about it basically. But my question here is just about SSMS (I know SE doesn't like mixing multiple questions into one).

Comment: I hope this link helps you https://blogs.sentryone.com/team-posts/latest-builds-management-studio/